# PHP set variable before next page load

Tags: php

I am trying to set the variable before the page is loaded after the link is pressed.
so the url will be http://www.blah.com/firstPage.php?varname=1

```
<?php
$varname = 0;
?>


<a onclick="varname = 1;" href="page.php?varname=<?php echo $varname ?>" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View Project</a>
```

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing PHP and Javascript. this is not possible: PHP executes on the server, Javascript executes on the client. By the time the page is loaded and the link becomes clickable, PHP will have LONG since completed its job and be done.

Since you're setting the `1` in javascript, you'll have to use javascript code to rewrite the href. Why not simply have

```
<a onclick="window.location = 'page.php?varname=1';">...</a>
```

instead? Of course, using JS for clickable links is horrible from a usability standpoint. onclick handlers do NOT show up in the status bar so users can't see what they're clicking on, and users with no JS won't be able to do ANYTHING.

Comment: So why don't you propose to put `href="page.php?varname=1"` in the a-tag? Would be the better solution in this case in my opinion.

Comment: `href` is fine. I'm saying don't do it as an `onclick`

Comment: I understood that. You explained very well why this isn't a good solution. I'm just proposing to you to include the href-solution in your answer as well, so it doesn't only show the "bad" way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this?

```
<?php

    $varname = 0; // set the var here

    header('location: page.php?varname=' . $varname);

?>
```

Unless I misunderstood the question.